# Obtaining List of all Xorg Displays

Tags: c, linux, unix, xorg, window-managers

I would like to know how I can obtain a list of all Xorg displays on my system, along with a list of screens associated with each display. I spent some time looking through the Xlib documentation, but was not able to find a function that does what I want. Please assume that I have no other dependencies other than a POSIX-complaint OS and X (e.g., no GTK). If what I ask is not possible assuming these minimal dependencies, then a solution using other libraries is fine.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The only way I know of to get a list of displays is to check the `/tmp/.X11-unix` directory.

Once you do that, you can use Xlib to query each display for more information.

Per example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(void) {
    DIR* d = opendir("/tmp/.X11-unix");

    if (d != NULL) {
        struct dirent *dr;
        while ((dr = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
            if (dr->d_name[0] != 'X')
                continue;

            char display_name[64] = ":";
            strcat(display_name, dr->d_name + 1);

            Display *disp = XOpenDisplay(display_name);
            if (disp != NULL) {
                int count = XScreenCount(disp);
                printf("Display %s has %d screens\n",
                    display_name, count);

                int i;
                for (i=0; i<count; i++)
                    printf(" %d: %dx%d\n",
                        i, XDisplayWidth(disp, i), XDisplayHeight(disp, i));

                XCloseDisplay(disp);
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running the above gives me this output with my current displays/screens:

```
Display :0 has 1 screens
 0: 3046x1050
Display :1 has 2 screens
 0: 1366x768
 1: 1680x1050
```

Never found a better way of listing X displays other than that. I'd very much like to know if any better alternative exists.

Comment: It looks like the display sockets can be in `/usr/spool/sockets/X11/` for hpux and `/var/tsol/doors/.X11-unix/` for some configurations of solaris. Though, I think these are rare enough that you could just rely on `/tmp/.X11-unix/`.

Comment: With libx11-dev run `gcc -o screen screen.c -L/usr/X11/lib -lX11`.

Comment: Silly question, but... how were you able to have the second display server `:1`? I'd like to mock this, but all environments I've ever seen only have the primary display server `:0`

Comment: @MestreLion I *think* the :0 or :1 is the display, which contains the screens. So if you wanted to have an additional display one way of doing that would be to switch to a different tty and starting an addition desktop session

Comment: @MestreLion You can have more display servers by running multiple Xorg sessions. Xorg is just a program running on your computer, so you can run more. Multiseat Xorg is such an example (https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/Multiseat/).

Answer (score 5):

Like netcoder wrote, the problem has two distinct parts:

1. Connection to the X server

   The process establishes a connection to an X server using `XOpenDisplay()`. The connection is torn down using `XCloseDisplay()`. netcoders code in this thread is a good example of how to do it correctly.

   As netcoder mentioned, the problem is that there is no reliable way find out which X servers a process can connect to. His code checks the typical location where the X sockets are, `/tmp/.X11-unix/`. That approach does *not* work at all if the user is remotely connected, for example via SSH (with X forwarding enabled). In that case there is really only the `DISPLAY` environment variable (and perhaps some trickery wrt. `~/.Xauthority` files).

   Unfortunately, I do not know of any better method either. I personally prefer to use a per-user configuration file -- say `~/.application/displays` --, where the user can list the server names the application should try to connect in the same format as the `DISPLAY` environment variable, in addition to the default one. It is not automatic (netcoder's code is), but this approach suits me better.
2. Finding out about the screens provided by an X server

   `XScreenCount()` will return the number of screens provided by the X server the process is currently connected to. If you only need the screen dimensions, follow netcoders example. For more detailed information, use `XScreenOfDisplay(Display,index)` to obtain the `Screen` pointers; `0` <= `index` < `XScreenCount(Display)`.

   In C code, the macros `ScreenCount()` and `ScreenOfDisplay()` are usually a bit more efficient than the actual function calls.