# Wayland session and XWayland configuration at example of KDE

Tags: desktop, kde-plasma, wayland

Dear stackoverflow users,
I am trying to understand how a Wayland session gets invoked at the example KDE to configure [XWayland for sandboxing](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/issues/3602).
The [Wayland manual for XWayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/docs/html/ch05.html) is unclear about my sections and neither explains the commands/utils how to handle Wayland/XWayland.

1. How can I check via command which programs are getting (in future) invoked as Xwayland server?
2. Are the XWayland configuration files also at `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` for the client and `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc` for the one global server?
3. [These](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/xserver.html) [instructions](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/xserver.html) are abit unlucky without command examples. Does this mean I just need to set $DISPLAY and the Wayland server will start/connect to a xserver?

```
DISPLAY=":5" application        #will this use x11 or Wayland before running it?
```

4. `kdestart5` starts KDE, but where do I see the configs?
5. If setting `$DISPLAY` yourself is possible, does this mean that multiple x11 instances can coexist on the same Wayland session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To my knowledege, I cant, since the feature is not provided yet. The compositor simply falls back to Xwayland, which may be provide a false sense of security for the user. Retrospectively you can use xeyes.
   [correct me, if I am wrong]
2. Xwayland/Wayland configuration files are not standartized and thus the display manager decides where to put things.
3. The compositor does handle this. The code is the documentation how/no documentation exists. `ls /tmp/.X11-unix/` shows up `X0 X1`, so X0 is still the xorg display server.
4. The config is given by `sddm --example-config`.
5. The display manager handles the x11 instance, which for simplicity is exactly 1.

All in all there is lacking of documentation and [utilities](https://superuser.com/questions/1484068/how-to-check-if-a-program-use-wayland-or-x11-in-linux) like [checking in shell what display an application uses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546188/how-detect-the-display-used-by-xorg-x-and-xwayland) for Wayland and Xwayland.
Common things like using `ps auxww | grep X` do not work anymore under Wayland.

However even these settings were not [reliable on Xorg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367354/obtaining-list-of-all-xorg-displays), which is just painful with respect to availability of XDG_BASE as standard.