# How to add a background images to several screens for X11/Wayland using Go?

Tags: image, go, x11, wayland

I make a custom wallpaper setter for window managers in Go. Currently I use `github.com/xyproto/wallutils` project, which in turn depends on `feh`.

For one screen I can use its dimensions to create the image of exact size, and all works well, but if there are several screens with different dimensions connected to a computer, this approach does not work.

For the exact image I use [feh's 'fill' option](https://codeberg.org/dimus/muro/src/commit/e17c56b44aadcf564bbfdd54c997791241193767/pkg/muro.go#L170), which would work correctly only for one of the monitors.

What I want to do is to create images of correct dimensions for each screen and send them as background images to corresponding screens either in X11 or Wayland. How can I achieve this in Go?

Comment: You have a working code (as you claim) for a single monitor. What is the problem? You don't know how to detect if and what displays are available?

Comment: I love how [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/chat) confidently suggests the package "`xgraphics/window`" to get the `Screen`(s) with `screens, err := window.Screens()`. Except, as far as I can see, "`xgraphics/window`" does not exist!

Comment: @icza, I added an explanation in the question why current feh-based approach works only for one monitor.

Comment: Please share more details, like your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase, currently, for a single display, I use feh binding from wallutils https://codeberg.org/dimus/muro/src/commit/e5876d787c0fb6f683548404c7c5a917deccae30/pkg/muro.go#L171

However this approach does not allow sending image individually to each display.

Comment: As usual, please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requirements:

- send different wallpapers to different monitors
- call from Go
- use `feh` underneath

**muro and wallutils**

`wallutils` specifies a `WM` interface that provides, among other things, the `SetWallpaper` method. There are corresponding implementations of this interface for a number of different window managers.

The Go package `muro` in turn uses `wallutils`. Based on the flag `WithAnyWindowManager` it will either use wallutils' `SetWallpaperCustom` method which selects a concrete `SetWallpaper` implementation based on the detected window manager or just directly call `SetWallpaper` of the `feh` variant.

**wallutils and feh**

The specific display mode depends on how it is called, but `SetWallpaper` in wallutils feh.go would basically call `feh` in your case as follows:

```
    feh --bg-fill <image file name>
```

Two notes:

- here `feh` sets the wallpaper on all screens to the very same image
- therefore it's not directly supported to have different images

Also, wallutils' readme explicitly states:

> **Setting a wallpaper per monitor**

> Setting a wallpaper per monitor is not supported, yet. Currently, a wallpaper is set for all monitors.

see https://github.com/xyproto/wallutils#setting-a-wallpaper-per-monitor

**Possible solution**

Since you can determine monitors and resolution, we focus on sending the predefined images in the correct order as background images under use of `feh` to the appropriate screens.

`feh` itself supports setting different wallpapers per monitor. You just call `feh` with the different images having different resolutions. The order is guaranteed to be the same as determined by a call to `xrandr --listmonitors`.

After determining the order and taking it as a given, the simplest possible GO program would look something like this (see also wallutil's utility function [run](https://github.com/xyproto/wallutils/blob/232c4fd9de2002294ee0821ec095620220b0f0d0/utils.go#L63)):

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    args := []string{"--bg-fill", "1.png", "2.png"}
    cmd := exec.Command("feh", args...)
    if _, err := cmd.CombinedOutput(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

(tested with `FluxBox` window manager)

Provided `feh` works with the appropriate window manager and there are the two prepared images in the go directory, this is the simplest case. Of course, one could also programmatically determine the screens and dynamically adjust the call of `feh`.

Since `feh` does not work in every environment, wallutils provides concrete implementations of its `WM` interface for a number of window manager environments (Cinnamon, Deepin, Gnome, Mate, Pekwm, Plasma, Sway, Weston, Xfce4). This is of course very cool. However, if you wanted to create an MR for wallutils, you would probably have to do so in all variants, at least those that support it.

Comment: It worked for me as well in Qtile wm, thank you! I am going to pass your answer to the developers of wallutils, in case if they will decide to add this functionality there too.

Comment: I'm the wallutils developer and I would love to add this functionality, I just haven't gotten around to it yet. Thanks for using wallutils. :)

Comment: Thank you for providing such a great library. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [`vbsw/xlib`](https://github.com/vbsw/xlib), which includes:

- [`XOpenDisplay()`](https://github.com/vbsw/xlib/blob/375c0d9524516d857a95e90e9d82b05dea582ecb/xlib.go#L36), which returns a Display (`C.Display`)
- [`XScreenCount`](https://github.com/vbsw/xlib/blob/375c0d9524516d857a95e90e9d82b05dea582ecb/xlib.go#L69), for the number of "screens"
- [`XScreenOfDisplay`](https://github.com/vbsw/xlib/blob/375c0d9524516d857a95e90e9d82b05dea582ecb/xlib.go#L75) which gets a Screen for a given "screen number"
- [`XWidthOfScreen`](https://github.com/vbsw/xlib/blob/375c0d9524516d857a95e90e9d82b05dea582ecb/xlib.go#L81)
- [`XHeightOfScreen`](https://github.com/vbsw/xlib/blob/375c0d9524516d857a95e90e9d82b05dea582ecb/xlib.go#L87)

That is inspired from the C implementation "[Obtaining List of all Xorg Displays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11368019/6309)".

Comment: Thank you for the link, @VonC, wallutils also provide information about number of displays and their dimensions as well https://github.com/xyproto/wallutils/blob/main/backend.go#L37, what is missing for me is an ability to send an image to displays' background according to the dimensions of each of them.